# Getting a user access token in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, web2py, access-token, instagram-api

I'm developing a web2py app which imports pictures from Facebook and Instagram based on an event tag.

To do this, I'm trying to use Kenneth Reitz's requests module (https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests), because then I'd be able to make API calls to both websites using a single approach. But I'm having difficulty understanding how to get a **user** access token. If I'm not mistaken, the web2py manual describes how to get an **app** access token, which is not what I want (http://web2py.com/books/default/chapter/29/09/access-control#Other-login-methods-and-login-forms, under OAuth2.0).

So how do I get a user access token with the right permissions? If possible, I would like to do it in python.

Comment: Normally questions regarding the need for an example is frown upon unless you have some piece of code that you almost got working and need help with etc. Could you give us some code that is almost what you need but is struggling with? Or are you using a identical copy of an example code?

Comment: I don't have any working code as I have no direction. I have found no way to create a user access token in Python, unless I've misunderstood the example given. I'm here mostly looking for a direction to continue searching in.

Comment: You might be missunderstanding the difference between the app token and a user token. A user token sure enough gives you all the permissions a traditional facebook login does, your feed, your friends etc. But the app can do virtually the same (except accessing friends direct information without them accepting your app). A user token is obtained by showing the user a official facebook login page that redirects you to your application (in this case, web application). This login page is almost certainly mandatory for a user access token I think.